# Null check returns true for non-null value

Tags: c#

Having an odd problem.  It's happened a few times over the years, but I've never been able to figure out why.  Always solved it by rearranging the code I had in place, but would like to know is there's a more proper way of dealing with it, or at least figuring out what's behind it.

Non-working version:

```
public bool CaptureFrame(ArrayCache cache)
{
    if (cache == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cache");

    DataArray frame = cache.CacheData;

    if (frame == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cache.CacheData");


    // do stuff
}
```

Working version:

```
public bool CaptureFrame(ArrayCache cache)
{
    if (cache == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cache");

    if (cache.CacheData == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cache.CacheData");

    DataArray frame = cache.CacheData;


    // do stuff
}
```

The problem is this: frame is *not* null (at least according to the debugger, and by any measure I can trace of the code), however when it does the `if (frame == null)` check, it comes out true and throws the exception.  I rewrote to check cache.CacheData and it works fine, but it really shouldn't make any difference to the code logic.

I managed to find one other question on the site with a similar problem, which ended up being related to the == and != operators being overloaded.  Those operators are not overloaded for the class in question in my code, and it's a standalone class so there's nothing for it to inherit.

Edit: John Saunders requested code for the CacheData property:

```
private DataArray cacheData;

public DataArray CacheData
{
    get
    {
        return cacheData;
    }
    set
    {
        cacheData = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `DataArray`? Is it a value type by any chance?

Comment: What is the type of `CacheData`?

Comment: Those blocks are not the same - you have `DataArray frame = cache.CacheData` in the first, and `DataArray frame = cache.Frame` in the second. Also, besides the `==` operator being overloaded, I would also check for [`implicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) type casts.

Comment: Did you paste the code right. One version says `frame = cache.CacheData` and the other says `frame = cache.Frame`.

Comment: This looks like a threading problem. Please show the code of the `CacheData` property. Also, do not use `ArgumentNullException` for `cache.CacheData`. It is not an argument.

Comment: DataArray and CacheData are both classes to encapsulate other information.

`DataArray frame = cache.Frame` is a typo; was trying to write things as simply as possible, and copied the wrong bit there.  I'll edit original post.

Comment: Is this a multi threaded application?

Comment: @JohnSaunders `Edit: John Saunders requested code for the CacheData property:`  I hope you understand it now :)

Comment: Yes, it's multi-threaded.  I have not been able to find any race conditions related to this.  This portion is obviously all handled within a single thread, and there are several locks between here and anything that could change this object.  Also, given the constant failure of the null check, this object was never sent on to any further stage that could modify it in the first place.

Comment: @dsmith, Probably there is race condition and until you show your full code, I don't  expect you'll get a correct answer.

Comment: Unless you can provide a small, *complete* program that we can compile that consistently reproduces the problem it's unlikely that anyone can help you with this.

Comment: @Eric: Was kind of afraid of that.  I'm not really sure how to condense it down to a test case that would actually replicate the problem, since I'm not exactly sure how the problem is being caused.  Simple checks like this work perfectly fine in tons of other parts of the program code; I have no idea what's different about this chunk.  I was more hoping for an idea of where to even start looking to find out what's really going on, such as maybe an idea of the IL code to look for (and how to go about examining it).

Comment: @L.B: For reference on the threading, the property setter for `ArrayCache.DataArray` is called:
1) Within the same class, on same thread, prior to calling this function, to create the DataArray that is going to be used.
2) From a higher level UI class that may (indirectly) clear out all existing caches before starting up the code that leads to this function.  Cannot be repeated while this is running.
and... that's about it. It's not even cleared further down the threading chain like I was thinking, it's just noted as not used anymore so it can be reused at (1).

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are mapping the exception in the non working one then calling 
DataArray frame = cache.CacheData; 
but what if cache.CacheData if null then you are assigning it to DataFrame.. it's always best in my opinion to do the Check for null first before assigning or assuming your second one looks fine.. prehaps instead of throwing an exception maybe you could trap the exception and try some test cases for both scenarios